# Верхний регистр текста Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi

Сделала вот такой код:

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var t:TStringlist;
    i:integer;
begin
t:=TStringlist.Create;
t.LoadFromFile('1.txt'); //файл в папке с программой
for i:=0 to t.Count-1 do
t.Strings[i]:=AnsiUpperCase(t.Strings[i]);
t.SaveToFile('2.txt');
end;
end.
```

**Переделываю на чтение построчно (что делаю не так?):**

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var f1,f2:TextFile;
s:string;
i:integer;
begin
if OpenDialg1.Execute then begin
AssignFile(f1,OpenDialog1.FileName);
AssignFile(f2,ExtractFileDir(OpenDialg1.FileName));
Reset(f1); Rewrite(f2);
    while not Eof(f1) do begin
        Readln(f1,s);
f1:=AnsiUpperCase(f2);
Writeln(f2,s);
CloseFile(f1);
CloseFile(f2);
end;
end;
end;
end
```

Comment: Не форматируете код. Если бы Вы соблюдали отступы в коде - вопроса бы не возникло

Comment: Как заголовок вопроса связан с телом вопроса?

Comment: Вы уверены в своей правке, что теперь пишете в имя существующей папки?
 `AssignFile(f2,ExtractFileDir(OpenDialg1.FileName));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вынесите код, закрывающий файлы, из цикла.

```
  ...
  s := AnsiUpperCase(s);
  Writeln(f2,s);
end;
CloseFile(f1);
CloseFile(f2);
```

Comment: Сделала, но в этом месте выдает ошибку: f1:=AnsiUpperCase(f2);

Comment: @Татьяна Представляете, насколько мне было бы легче, если бы Вы сказали, какую ошибку?

Comment: Но мы не ищем легких путей - смотрите добавленную строчку в ответе.

Comment: Вот эта ошибка: [dcc32 Error] Unit2.pas(38): E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'AnsiUpperCase' that can be called with these arguments.

Comment: @Татьяна Спасибо, уже не надо :).

Comment: Igor Вы как всегда на высоте. Спасибо вам большое. Я может и кажусь наглой, но я очень любознательная девушка. И за этого может и кажусь наглой. На самом деле я простая и ко всему отношусь с позитивом. По этому не судите строго, еще раз спасибо.

Comment: В ряде случаев  использование AnsiUpperCase(s) излишне, а в некоторых даже ошибочно. ToUpper будет надёжнее - см. ответ от @VladChapl

Answer (score 3):

На самом деле нужно смотреть на функции ToUpper и ToLower (вроде появились в Delphi 2009), потому что AnsiUpperCase на юникодовском тексте не будет работать как нужно.

Подробнее на русском тут http://www.webdelphi.ru/2010/03/modul-character-rabota-s-simvolami-stroki/